# match occurence of 2 patterns with perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have 2 regex patterns `[\d\d]` and `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]` and i want to check if a string has those patterns in any number and in any order and only those patterns separated by comma how can i do this with perl ?

- for example string `ex,xy,gf,55,66-> match`
- for example string `22,24,25,56,ff ->match`
- for example string `2FF,24,25,56,ff -> not match`

Comment: Is `2f` a valid match?

Comment: `\w` already contains numbers `\d`, which means you can also get mixed matches of letters and numbers, such as the one Tim mentioned above `2f`. You need to decide if that is a valid match. Also, `[\d\d]` is a redundant expression which simplifies to `\d`.

Comment: no its not a valid match only characthers that what i mean i revisted the quesition

Comment: For very large strings, you probably need a pattern that matches the invalid form. I posted the negative permutations if you are interrested.

Comment: Just a FYI: In Perl, every answered regex here I tested and fails on strings over 400k. I don't know why. The negative regex I posted works on any size string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
^(([A-Za-z]{2}|\d\d),)*([A-Za-z]{2}|\d\d)$
```

[Tested on regexe](http://www.regexe.com/)

Got the following result :

[image: Result]

Comment: The parentheses immediately around `\d\d` are superfluous, otherwise +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my $pattern1 = '\d';
my $pattern2 = '[a-zA-Z]';
my $string = ('ex,xy,gf,55,66');
my $warning = 0;

my @split = split(/,/, $string);
foreach (@split){
    unless (($_ =~ /^$pattern1{2}$/) or ($_ =~ /^$pattern2{2}$/)) {
        $warning++;
    } 
}

print "$string -> match\n" if ($warning == 0);
print "$string -> no match" if ($warning != 0);
```

Outputs:

```
ex,xy,gf,55,66 -> match
```

Same code, different string:

```
my $string = ('22,2f,ex,xy,gf,2FF');
```

Outputs:

```
22,2f,ex,xy,gf,2FF -> no match
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using `/^(?:[a-z]{2},?|\d\d,?)+$/i`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @elems = split /,/;
    my @match = grep /^(?:\d{2}|[a-z]{2})$/i, @elems;
    print "$_ -> ", ( @elems == @match ? '' : 'not ' ), "match\n"
}

__DATA__
ex,xy,gf,55,66
22,24,25,56,ff
2FF,24,25,56,ff
```

Output:

```
ex,xy,gf,55,66 -> match
22,24,25,56,ff -> match
2FF,24,25,56,ff -> not match
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Making the commas optional will allow strings like `aaaa` or `22aa` to match (length dividable by 2).

Comment: @TLP - Thank you for the regex-problem catch.  Have reposted my original solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
^((?>[a-z]{2}|[0-9]{2})(?>,(?1)|$))
```

or this:

```
^(?>(?>[a-z]{2}|[0-9]{2})(?>,|$))+$
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this in Perl, I came up with this.
I tested all the answers posted in Perl. The problems come from trying to match
very large strings. Mostly ones > 256 K. Perl seems to not find a match, where at
a lesser size, it does. Maybe its a setting I'm not using, I don't know..
The exception was Casimir's recursive regex, which takes like a minute to match a 3 meg bufffer.

So for grins, I put together a regex that matches the negative of what is allowed.
The 15 meg buffer takes max 10 seconds on my machine depending where the failure (match)
was, or  10 seconds if it passes. The notable thing is that there is no accumulation of
capture information, maybe thats why it can handle large buffers.

```
 $test = "ex,xy,gt,55,66,";
 for (0 .. 19 ) { $test .= $test; }
 $test .= "3a3";

 print "\nlength = ", length($test), "\n------------\n";

 if ( $test =~ m/

     # \d(?:[a-z]|\d{2})|[a-z](?:\d|[a-z]{2})|[^a-z\d,]|,(?:.?,|$)|^,

      \d 
      (?: [a-z] | \d{2} )
   |  
      [a-z] 
      (?: \d | [a-z]{2} )
   |  
      [^a-z\d,] 
   |  
      , 
      (?: .? , | $ )
   |  
      ^ ,

 /xg )

 {  print "Found error at pos = ", pos($test), "\n";  }
 else
 {  print "Passed test!\n";  }

 __END__

 Output >>

 length = 15728643
 ------------
 Found error at pos = 15728642
```